# Custom post types & Advanced Custom Fields code is not working

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using custom post types to render icon snippets on the screen. Using Custom Post Types and Advanced Custom Fields to render 6 inline icons sprites on the screen ... the intent is to decide which icon to use by modifying the CSS Sprite. sprints aren't rendering. Here's the code:

The custom Fields is in course_feature post type and in the Course Features Field Group, I listed 6 sprites in the acf choices field.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course_feature', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
    <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <i class="<?php the_field('course_feature_icon'); ?>"</i>
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        </div><!-- end col -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Is that the complete code? `the_post()` doesn't render anything. You need to output the template yourself.

Comment: I have created ted the custom post type and advanced custom fields for my custom template … the code is calling the array "course_feature" to render post by id in ascending order. The output type and object is defined …

Comment: Here's the full code … I am setting the fields on the back end using "Custom Fields"

Comment: "Custom Fields" is "course_feature" and in the Course Features Field Group, I listed 6 sprites in the "choices" field and the  "post Type" is equal to "course_feature"
<div class="row"> 
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course_feature', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
  
 <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        
    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <i class="<?php the_field('course_feature_icon'); ?>"</i>
          
     <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
    </div><!-- end col -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: please edit your question accordingly instead of putting unreadable code snippets inside comments..

Comment: You haven't specified what you're storing in the custom field. Is it an image, a line of text, etc? What is the HTML being output. is it what you're expecting, or is it wrong? Would be helpful to know if you're expecting anyone to have a clue!!

Comment: I apologize. The output is supposed to be 6 sprite icons, posted in a horizontal line, atop of 6 fields of text. The text does render correctly. The sprite icons do not show at all.

Comment: I am using WP_Query to loop Custom Fields, Custom Post Type of 6 Menu Icons. The loop code is: